# HTML5 Canvas draw rectangle on image of canvas

Tags: html, canvas, series

I shown series of images into my canvas (series of medical images). I'd like to draw a rectangle on specific image. The reectangle will be disappeared if I scroll to other images. How can I do?

Below is my code. The rectangle is shown well but when I scroll to next image, the rectangle also keep display.

```
const context = eventData.canvasContext.canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.rect(Number(203.353) - 13, Number(322.691) - 13, 25, 25);
context.stroke();
```

Thanks,
Lam

Comment: Create a fiddle or use snippet here , to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Durga: Sorry, I can't reproduce issue on fiddle because using api https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneTools